# RuntimeWarning: invalid value encountered in sqrt return np.sqrt((EA**2)-(m**2))/(EA)

Tags: python, function, numpy, error-handling, sqrt

as the title suggests, I keep getting an error with a square root. I suppose it is probably due to the fact that there may be a negative number under the square root, but I can't seem to find it.

The issue comes from this line of code:

```
lf_rf_momentum_diff_neutrino_pi = find4mtm_C_lf(140, 105, 5*10**-4, np.pi/6, np.pi/2, 1e3)-four_momentum(Enu_rf_pi, 140, 105, 5*10**-4, np.pi/6, np.pi/2)
print(lf_rf_momentum_diff_neutrino_pi)
```

giving me this error message:

```
<ipython-input-19-f3687c795889>:5: RuntimeWarning: invalid value encountered in sqrt
  return np.sqrt((EA**2)-(m**2))/(EA)
```

I have isolated the issue to the function `find4mtm_C_lf` which itself is a function that calls upon other functions listed below. It is defined as follows:

```
def find4mtm_C_lf(m_A, m_B, m_C, theta, phi, EA):
    return np.array([boost(four_momentum(energy_func(m_A, m_B, m_C), m_A, m_B, m_C, theta, phi), gamma(m_A, energy_func(m_A,m_B,m_C)),beta_calc(m_A, EA))])
```

The individual functions inside are defined as follows:

**boost**

```
def boost(four_mom, gamma_general, beta):
    z_boost = np.array([[gamma_general, 0, 0, -gamma_general*beta],[0, 1, 0, 0], [0, 0, 1, 0], [-gamma_general*beta, 0, 0, gamma_general]])
    boost_general = np.matmul(z_boost, four_mom)
    return boost_general
```

**gamma**

```
def gamma(m, EA):
    gamma_general=1/((1-beta_calc(m, EA)**2)**0.5)
    return gamma_general
```

**energy_func**

```
def energy_func(m_A, m_B, m_C):
    E = ((m_A**2)+(m_C**2)-(m_B**2))/(2*m_A)
    return E
```

**beta_calc**

```
def beta_calc(m, EA):
    return np.sqrt((EA**2)-(m**2))/(EA)
```

I think I have further isolated the issue to the m_A in `find4mtm_C_lf`. when m_A is defined as 60, it works, but if m_A = 61 or greater, I get the sqrt error.

Doing the `np.sqrt((EA**2)-(m**2))/(EA)` calculation by hand, where EA = 1e3, m = m_A = 140 works fine, especially since EA >> m so there shouldn't be a square root error.

**Edit 1 - using beta_calc to generate a value**

This value `b_pi` is actually used in `lf_rf_momentum_diff_neutrino_pi` although rather than being inputted directly into the function, it is recalculated by the function.

```
b_pi=-beta_calc(140,1*10**3)
print('The value of beta in the lab frame seen in the parent particle rest frame is',b_pi)

The value of beta in the lab frame seen in the parent particle rest frame is -0.990151503558925
```

***Edit 2 - Definition of four_momentum***

```
def four_momentum(E_C, m_A, m_B, m_C, theta, phi):
    four_mom= np.insert(momentum_vector(E_C, m_C, theta, phi), 0, energy_func(m_A, m_B, m_C))
    return four_mom
```

***Edit 3 - momentum_vector function***

```
def momentum_vector(E_C, m_C, theta, phi):
    p= ((E_C**2)-(m_C**2))**0.5
    p_three_vector= p*np.array([np.sin(theta)*np.cos(phi),np.sin(theta)*np.sin(phi),np.cos(theta)])
    return p_three_vector
```

Comment: looking at the error the issue is at beta_calc. can you try to make a try-except segment here and print the values in case of error and sys.exit to check if the value inside the root is positive ? Maybe the issue is at the definition of EA or m's values and it causes issues here.

Comment: Sorry I am very new to python and am a bit confused on what this means. I google try-except, and from what I understand, it will try to execute the command as if there is no error?

Comment: Also, I should add that I had previously already used beta_calc to generate a value (check the newest edit to the main post) (this value is to be used in lf_rf_momentum_diff_neutrino_pi, I just needed to define find4mtm_C_lf as generally as possible just in case I needed to use it for different values generated by beta_calc

Comment: that's it and when an error is supposed to occur it don't stop it goes to the except part which allows you to print the values only at the time the error occurs. Would you add the four_momentum function so we can try and run it ourselves and help you debug it quicker?

Comment: I've added the four momentum function to edit 2. Thanks

Comment: Added the momentum_vector function to Edit 3. My bad, I should have included it earlier.

Answer (score 0):

When I run this for me the first values encountered by beta_calc is m = 140 and EA = 30.6... so your assumption that E >> m is false. that's why you get a warning. the sqrt return a nan (not a number).

If you actually need complex number you can swap `np.sqrt((EA**2)-(m**2))/(EA))` to `np.sqrt(complex((EA**2)-(m**2))/(EA)))` it will return complex instead of NaN and you can actually do operation on it. But still might have to troubleshoot to know where your issues come from with E being less than m.

**1st Assumption**

```
find4mtm_C_lf(140, 105, 5*10**-4, np.pi/6, np.pi/2, 1e3)
```

masses are 140 105 and 5e-4 and energy is 100

I think there is an issue with the orders of magnitude. Your energy might be in J and your mass in kg for you to use `(EA**2)-(m**2)` but here it can be that you didn't put everything in standard units. My English is limited when it comes to physics terms. I could explain why you intended to have E >> m but it doesn't appear here

**2nd Assumption**

In find4mtm_C_lf you apaprently replace EA by the value given by energy_func  instead of maybe passing EA that's why it goes from 100 to 36

```
def find4mtm_C_lf(m_A, m_B, m_C, theta, phi, EA):
return ... gamma(m_A, energy_func(m_A,m_B,m_C)) ...
```

and gamma require first m and then EA : `gamma(m, EA)`

Replacing `gamma(m_A, energy_func(m_A,m_B,m_C))` by `gamma(m_A, EA)` make the error disappeared but go check if it fits well with your model

Comment: I thought in this line 
`lf_rf_momentum_diff_neutrino_pi = find4mtm_C_lf(140, 105, 5*10**-4, np.pi/6, np.pi/2, 1e3)-four_momentum(Enu_rf_pi, 140, 105, 5*10**-4, np.pi/6, np.pi/2)`

I defined EA=1e3 so why would it give EA = 30.6?

Also, I should be getting a real number.

Comment: Thank you for the help! I just decided to make the very first function less general, and defined some of the necessary variables earlier, if that makes sense. I have what I need now. I really appreciate you taking your time to help me.